# strncat() is copying to the same string again

Tags: c, string, concatenation, string-concatenation

I am trying to concatenate two strings in C programming. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    /* code */
        char s1[3],s2[34];

        strncat(s1,"mv ",3);
        strncat(s2,"  /home/xxxxxxx/.local/share/Trash/",34);

        printf("%s \n",s1);

        return 0;

}
```

when I try to print the value in `s1` it prints `mv   /home/xxxxxxx/.local/share/Trash` as the output. Why is the value i am putting for s2 getting added with the string s1? If the question is already asked please put the link.

Comment: Using `strncat()` is really hard!  What is the number you provide as the length?  It isn't the total length available in `s2` (in your example); it is the length that is left after the current contents of `s2`, or `sizeof(s2) - strlen(s2) - 1` (assuming that you fix the problem that neither `s1` nor `s2` is a null-terminated string).  It isn't clear why you want the command in `s1` and the argument in `s2`, either.  You'd probably do better with `snprintf(s2, sizeof(s2), "%s %s", "mv", "/home/…");`.

Comment: Avoid using `strncat(a, b, sizeof(a));`.  After insuring `a` has a legit string in it, better to use `strncat(a, b, sizeof(a)-1);  a[sizeof(a)-1] = '\0';`.  This insures not too many `char` were concatenated and the array is `'\0'` terminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

s1 is defined as

```
char s1[3],
```

that is it has three elements (characters). When `strncat`  was executed

```
strncat(s1," mv",3);
```

this three elements were filled with { ' ', 'm', 'y' }

After that this array does not have the terminating zero.

Format specifier `%s` in printf function outputs a character array until the terminatig zero will be encountered. As array s1 does not have the terminating zero then the printf continues to output all bytes that are beyond the array. because after array s1 there is array s2

```
char s1[3],s2[34];
```

then it also is outputed until the terminating zero will be encountered.

Take into account that function `strncat` requires that the target string would be zero terminated. However you did not initialize s1. So the behaviour of the program is undefined.

If you want that the program would work correctly you have to define array s1 as having four characters

```
char s1[4] = { '\0' },s2[34];

strncat(s1,"mv ",4);
```

Or it would be simpler to write

```
char s1[4] = { '\0' },s2[34];

strcat( s1, "mv " );
```

Or even the following way

```
char s1[4],s2[34];

strcpy( s1, "mv " );
```

that is it would be better to use function `strcpy` instead of `strncpy`

Answer (score 3):

You have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code, as neither `s1` nor `s2` are initialized. Uninitialized (non-static) local variables have indeterminate values, and it's unlikely that they have the string terminator that `strncat` needs to find the end of the string to know where to *append* the source string.

After you fix the above, you also have another case of undefined behavior when `strncat` tries to write the string terminator beyond the end of the arrays.

Also, you're not concatenating the two strings, as `s1` and `s2` are two unrelated arrays, you just append the literal strings to the end of the two arrays but not together.

---

What you could do is to allocate an array big enough to hold both strings, and the string terminator, then *copy* the first string into the array, and then append the second string.

Or not use e.g. [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) (or [`_snprintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93.aspx) is using the Microsoft Windows runtime library) to construct the string.

```
char s[100];
snprintf(s, sizeof(s), "mv %s %s", somepath, someotherpath);
```

Answer (score 2):

> when I try to print the value in s1 it prints mv /home/ashwini/.local/share/Trash as the output.

This is undefined behavior: `s1` is not null-terminated, because it has a three-character string in a space of three characters; there's no space for the null terminator.

Your `s2` string buffer happens to be located in the adjacent region of memory, so it gets printed as well, until `printf` runs into the null terminator of `s2`.

Allocating more memory to `s1` and accounting for null termination would fix this problem:

```
char s1[4],s2[36];
s1[0] = '\0';
strncat(s1," mv", 4);
s2[0] = '\0';
strncat(s2,"  /home/xxxxxxx/.local/share/Trash/", 36);
```

However, `strncat` is not a proper function for working with regular strings: it is designed for use with fixed-length strings, which are no longer in widespread use. Unfortunately, C standard library does not include `strlcat`, which has proper semantic for "regular" C strings. It is available on many systems as a library extension, though.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/BngEAH)

Comment: Thanks. But now I am getting this : `*** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
`

Comment: @bhargav Your other string has the same problem, too. Take a look at the edit ([demo](http://ideone.com/BngEAH)).